# Regex to extract URL from text (with/without protocol and www or subdomains)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm looking to extract the URL from a text inside an element. I'm not very good with regexp but this is what I have done so far:

```
var regexp = /((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/i;
```

Please check this fiddle to see how my regexp works: http://jsfiddle.net/h70mr1zt/5/

This is the result that I need:

```
 1. stackoverflow => not found
 2. stackoverflow.com => found => stackoverflow.com
 3. www.stackoverflow.com => found => www.stackoverflow.com
 4. api.stackoverflow.com => found => api.stackoverflow.com
 5. http://www.stackoverflow.com => found => http://www.stackoverflow.com
 6. foo://www.stackoverflow.com => found => www.stackoverflow.com
 7. someone@stackoverflow.com => not found
 8. .com => not found
```

As you can see my fiddle I almost got everything right except for number **7** wherein it recognizes the domain part of the email address.

Comment: what seem incorrect in example 6?

Comment: @PhilipG `checks for valid domain name like .com, .net, .org, etc.?`

Comment: since their are qite a few valid topdomains that would generate a qite long match list... I would say: make a trade of on that be half and do something like: /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/

Comment: @PhilipG yes I think that's tough. I've disregarded it and updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a regex like

`^(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.(com|net|org)$`

see the example

http://regex101.com/r/uQ9aL4/1

how it works?

`^` anchors the regex at the begining of the line.

`(http:\/\/)?` mathces 0 or 1 occurence of `http://`

`(www\.)` matches 0 or 1 occurence of `www.`

`\w*` mathces any number of alphanum

`.(com|net|org)$` matches `.com` or `.net` or `.org`

`$` anchors the regex at the end of the string.

Comment: This is good but protocols and subdomains should not really matter. So that **api.stackoverflow.com** should be considered valid.

Comment: So I think removing `^` solves that right? but now email address becomes valid. See http://jsfiddle.net/h70mr1zt/2/

Comment: It matches `www..com` or `.net`

Comment: Thanks @nu11p01n73R. I updated my question and added the specific result that I need.

Comment: Yes it's correct on number 7 but pls check number 6 the url found is `foo://www.stackoverflow.com` the `foo://` should not be included since it's not a valid protocol. Only `http://` or `https://` I think should be included if there's any. Also you can drop the part that checks for `.com, .net or .org` since its hard to come up with all the valid list of domain names.

Comment: No :D Forgive me if my explanation is very poor. Pls see again the results I need above in my question. In number 6 the result should be `foo://www.stackoverflow.com => found => www.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: i have updated the fiddle. it would match `foo://www.stackoverflow.com` but not others as in example http://jsfiddle.net/h70mr1zt/15/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this regexp:

```
/^(?:[a-z]*?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/i
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h70mr1zt/12/)

**EDIT**

It is really hard to match ANY (even fictive) protocols and also exclude domain names from for example an email without using assertions (Lookahead && lookbehind, wich javascript doesn't support).

I would go for somethinglike [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h70mr1zt/22/):

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text(),
        regexp = /(^https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/i;
        regexpMail = /\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i;
    if((url = regexp.exec(text)) && !text.match(regexpMail)){
        $(this).append(' => <b>found</b> => <span>'+url[0]+'</span>');
    }else{
        $(this).append(' => <b class="nf">not found</b>');
    }
});
```

Break down:

```
          Matches http/s        matches the rest
                v                   v
regexp = /(^https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/i;
```

Since the above email will extract the domainname part of emails aswell you need a secound check to exclude emails, witch is done in this regexp:

```
 regexpMail = /\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i;
```

Doing all this results in your desired result. Some one else could probably put that in ONE regexp, but i'm not that good.

Comment: One thing on **number 6** : `foo://www.stackoverflow.com` the url found should be only `www.stackoverflow.com` since `foo://` is not a valid protocol. However if there is `http://` or `https://` it should extract with it like number 5.

Comment: you said that you wanted it to match even if foo:// was the protocol, if you dont want that then you'll need edit the first silent group to be: (https?:\/\/) instead of (?:[a-z]*?:\/\/) then it will only match http/s://

Comment: but then `foo://www.stackoverflow.com` is not found. It should be **found** but the url extracted should only `www.stackoverflow.com`. Sorry if I didn't explain that very well, the result for number 6 should be: `foo://www.stackoverflow.com => found => www.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: See my edit (It's an ugglier solution i know, but it'll work)